# How do I avoid duplicate IDs inserted by concurrent transactions?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I executed following PL/SQL in multiple sessions:

```
DECLARE
   x     NUMBER;
   y     NUMBER;
BEGIN
   x := 500;
   y := 0;
   WHILE (x > y)
   LOOP
       SET TRANSACTION 

       Select max(SERIAL_NO) INTO y from MY_TABLE;

       y := y + 1;

       insert into MY_TABLE S (S.SERIAL_NO, S.Request_id)
       values ((
                (select max(SERIAL_NO) from MY_TABLE) + 1
               )
              ,'B');

       Commit;

   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I still got duplicate entries in the table, how could this have happened?

Comment: Your code does not work, btw. SET TRANSACTION requires additional keywords. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/settransaction_statement.htm

Comment: ***Never**** use `max()` to "generate" primary keys. It simply doesn't work (as you have discovered). Use a `SEQUENCE` instead (as GWu said).

Comment: caveat: it's possible to use max() to generate unique ids, but the solution involves a performance-crushing serialization using locks.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Oracle has read-committed transaction isolation level.

If two sessions run for example like this:

```
Time  Session A                                 Session B
1     (Select max(SERIAL_NO) from MY_TABLE)+1
2                                               (Select max(SERIAL_NO) from MY_TABLE)+1
3     commit;
```

You will get duplicates for SERIAL_NO in your table, because sessions A + B see the same value for SERIAL_NO.

You need to use a sequence to ensure uniqueness (or implement your own flavor of semaphore - but I wouldn't recommend this).

Your `SET TRANSACTION` statement is missing some parameter, but this wouldn't help anyway (if you thought of `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;`)

See also http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm#sthref1981 on Serializable Isolation Transaction-Level and Data Concurrency and Consistency in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want duplicates in your tables, use UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS.